# Is the RefreshCommand from a ListView called on creation?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

When I put a breakpoint on my ListView's RefreshCommand, it is called right after the first line in my constructor. I never call for it by myself. Does a ListView do this on purpose?

After RefreshCommand is called, a refresh function is called with a succes/failed delagate. The succes delegate is called right after, which sets the ListView's IsRefreshing property to false. My ListView however never stops refreshing.

Code, all within the same page class:

```
public somePage(){
    list = new ListView(){
        ItemsSource = someSource,
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true,
    }
    list.RefreshCommand = new Command(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Run(() => refreshThread());
    });
}

private task refreshThread(){
    Succes succesCallBack = new Succes(onSucces);
    failedCallBack = new Failure(onFailed);
    refresh(succesCallBack, failedCallBack);
}

private void onSucces(dynamic result){
    //code to add//remove data from listview            
    list.IsRefreshing = false;
}

private void onFailed(string message){
    DisplayAlert("Alert", message, "ok");
    list.IsRefreshing = false;
}
```

Comment: Since it is now open-source, why not [check it yourself](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ListView.cs)? It doesn't seem like it. Where do you put your breakpoint exactly? If you mean `list.RefreshCommand = new Command(async () =>`, then yeah that is getting executed, if you put it on `await Task.Run(() => refreshThread());` then it is actually getting inside the refresh command.

Comment: @Geralt Versluis my breakpoints are in the refesh function itself and on the onSucces onFailed methods. The ListView isRefreshing property gets set to false, also a breakpoint on those, yet the listview doesnt stop refreshing, while I never tried to refresh it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for this answer as well, the problem for me was incorrect use of `async`/`await`.